# Button actionlistener calls another action listener in the same class

Tags: java

I have a submit button (and an action listener) which checks if the number inserted into a Futoshiki puzzle is legal (checking a 2D array for duplications etc)

In another method I have the actual grid with an action listener that gets the numbers and inserts them into the 2D array.

JButton acction listener

```
JButton isRight = new JButton("Check My Answer");
isRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (!(puzzle.isLegal())) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FutoshikiFrame.this,
        puzzle.getProblems(),
        "You made a mistake!",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FutoshikiFrame.this,
        "YOU WIN!",
        "YES THATS FINE",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    puzzle.printProblems.clear();

  }
});
```

Grid action listener

```
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
   String getInsertedValue = Emptysquare.getText();
   int getInsertedIntValue = Integer.parseInt(getInsertedValue);
   setSquareValue(r, c, getInsertedIntValue);
   System.out.print(getSquareValue(r, c));
 }
```

Is there a way I can access the keyReleased action listener from the JButton so it basically "submits" the contents of the grid and then checks if its legal?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just either keep a reference to that action listener and call the `keyReleased` method with a `null` value, or refactor out the content of `keyReleased` to an own method and call this method from both listeners.

Comment: How would I go about calling the `keyReleased` method? It's a _method_ inside my _setGrid method_. Sorry in advance if this is a bad thing to do

Comment: You for sure do not have a method inside a method as this is not possible. You maybe have a method in an anonymous class inside a method. But as I said, eihter assign the instance of this anonymous class to some variable the other scope has access to, or refacter the content of the method out into a method both scopes have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Although 2 other methods were given, here is an additional way you could go about it, but I'm not sure which would be best to use.

```
public class YourClass {
    JButton isRight;

    public YourClass() {
        this.isRight = new JButton();

        this.isRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                YourClass.this.isRight.getKeyListeners()[0].keyReleased(null);

                //Other action related code
            }
        });

        isRight.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                //Key related code
            }

            //Other required key listener methods
        });
    }
}
```